# error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:nanoid/generate.dart' in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So, I was using this package `nanoid` in my project. I made the projet a while ago, but now when I reopen it, I get error that, the part of package that I used isn't available. I tried some changes, but nothing happened. Can someone please tell me how to update my code in accordance to latest version of package?

```
import 'package:nanoid/generate.dart' as nanoid;  //error in this line

if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      var estimateObject = {
        'serial_no': nanoid.generate('1234567890', 10),
        'amount': _chargeController.value.text,
        'charge_type': _chargeTypeController.value.text,
        'unit': _neededUnitController.value.text,
        'completionTime': _timeOfCompletionController.value.text
      };

      databaseReference
          .collection("orders")
          .doc(widget.order["id"])
          .update({'estimate': estimateObject}).whenComplete(() {
        Navigator.pop(context, estimateObject);
      });
    }
```

Comment: nanoid previous package versions are outdated try to use latest version and successfully pub get.

Answer (score 0):

The package update doesn't have that file anymore. You should either **stay on the old version** (in your pubspec.yaml) or see if you can **use their new version** of package by checking their pub.dev project